# How to pass less parameters to ffmpeg when adding image overlays

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am doing processing of video with ffmpeg and I am trying to add image overlays at certain times. I have command something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i img_a.png -i img_xx.png -i some_third_image.png -i yy_img.png 
-filter_complex overlay=185:H-h-85:enable=between(t\\,1.1\\,2.3),overlay=285:H-h-415:enable=between(t\\,3.3\\,4.7),overlay=185:H-h-35:enable=between(t\\,5.7\\,6.0),overlay=45:H-h-515:enable=between(t\\,7.1\\,8.6) 
-c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast vid0.mp4
```

As I am forming/passing parameters to ffmpeg dynamically (programatically), there can be **really very very long parameters list**. **So large, I can even recieve message about too long parameter list (based on operating system) and then I cannot process video.** I would like to avoid this. I would like to know how to write code with ffmpeg so there would be less parameters passed to ffmpeg? For example, instead:

```
-i img_a.png -i img_xx.png -i some_third_image.png -i yy_img.png
```

can it be something like:

```
-i "img_a.png,img_xx.png,some_third_image.png,yy_img.png"
```

(Or something similar, where less parameters would be passed to ffmpeg). If it can, please provide example how to write such command in ffmpeg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular type of command, you can load the filtergraph from a file. All the images can be loaded inside the filtergraph.

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex_script mygraph.txt -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -preset veryfast vid0.mp4`

where mygraph.txt is

```
movie=img_a.png[a];
movie=img_xx.png[xx];
movie=some_third_image.png[3rd];
movie=yy_img.png[yy];
[0][a]overlay=185:H-h-85:enable=between(t\,1.1\,2.3)[0-a];
[0-a][xx]overlay=285:H-h-415:enable=between(t\,3.3\,4.7)[0-xx];
[0-xx][3rd]overlay=185:H-h-35:enable=between(t\,5.7\,6.0)[0-3rd];
[0-3rd][yy]overlay=45:H-h-515:enable=between(t\,7.1\,8.6)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But would this also allocate much memory as in case I've used? Or maybe less? It would be great if that is proper way to deal when memory consumption is increased by using many parameters.

Comment: How much memory the processing uses is distinct from shell character limits which is what your Q is about. This answer is a different way to carry out the same processing.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll test it by myself.

Comment: Btw, when I run command you've posted, I get: "Stream specifier 'a' in filtergraph description movie...  matches no streams.". Is something wrong in the mygraph.txt?

Comment: I think it should be [0-a][xx]..., not [0a][xx]... fot the second image.